# Connection to SQL server fails at first attempt

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am having a brain freeze at the moment and I cannot figure out why is this happening?

The first code fails but the second one works.

**[CODE 1] - Fails**

```
Dim cnString As String =  $"server={TbServer.Text};User Id={TbUsername.Text};
                          Password={TbPassword.Text};database={TbDb.Text};
                          Connect Timeout=60;Persist Security Info=True;
                          Pooling='true';Max Pool Size=200"

Using sqlConnection As New SqlConnection(cnString)
    sqlConnection.Open()
End Using
```

**[CODE 2] - Works**

The code fails in this version when the value if `i=1` but connects in the 2nd loop when `i=2`

```
Dim cnString As String =  $"server={TbServer.Text};User Id={TbUsername.Text};
                          Password={TbPassword.Text};database={TbDb.Text};
                          Connect Timeout=60;Persist Security Info=True;
                          Pooling='true';Max Pool Size=200"

Dim errMsg As String = ""

For i = 1 To 5
    Try
        Using sqlConnection As New SqlConnection(cnString)
            sqlConnection.Open()
            errMsg = ""
            Exit For
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        errMsg = ex.Message
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End Try
Next

If errMsg <> "" Then
    MessageBox.Show(errMsg, AppTitle, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Exit Sub
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Connection Successful", AppTitle, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
End If
```

The error message that I am getting for the first one is

[image]

Other Details (If required)

```
VS Version: 2019
SQL Server: 2017
.NET Framework: 4.8
Username/Password is correct
```

Comment: Check the SQL Server error log for related messages. Perhaps the database is set to auto close, causing slowness on the first attempt. Check with `SELECT name, is_auto_close_on FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'YourDatabase';`

Comment: Does it always work if you specify the server's IPv4 address? e.g.: `192.168.0.47,1433` If you have an IPv6 network have you checked that the target SQL Server is enabled to listen on both IPv6 as well as the IPv4 ports?

Comment: Is the database set to autoclose and the engine takes too long to bring it online?

Comment: It unlikely to help with this problem, but it would be better to use an [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder) to build the connection string: it will take care of things like semi-colons in the password.

Comment: What is the SQL Server error number?

Comment: @Dan Guzman, SMor, I'm not sure, but we didn't set it. I can confirm when I reach home. What is the default value for auto-close?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, I'm using machine name and that is the same PC on which app is running. Does it matter whether I put IP address or machine name?

Comment: @PradeepKumar, I believe the default auto close for new databases varies by edition and maybe version too. Ultimately, the value used is from the model database so you can always change for new databases going forward with `ALTER DATABASE model SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF;`. The root cause of your error might be something else so check the SQL Server error log.

Comment: In your second code snippet, what is FullConnectionString and where does that come from?  Or is that a copy paste error in the question?

Comment: @Hursey, it is a copy/paste error. It should be cnString. I have made correction to the question now.